# MySQL view linking 3 fields to the same field in another table with a different value

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, `users` and `user_images`. In the `users` table, each user has 3 sizes which are identified by a foreign key in the `users` table which is the primary key of the `user_images` table. So `users.small_image_id`, `users.medium_image_id`, and `users.large_image_id` are all referencing different row in the `user_images` table.
I'm attempting to write a view where all you see is the `image_url` for each image size called `small_image_url`, `medium_image_url`, and `large_image_url`. How do I go about differentiating the value for these columns from the same table? Thank you for your help!

So the resulting view schema would end up looking something like...

```
    user_id | user_name | small_image_url | medium_image_url | large_image_url
```

Comment: Do you actually want three separate url columns in your view, or one single column?

Comment: Yes, 3 URL columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join three times to the user_images table to combine the three images sizes as columns in the same row with the respective user.

```
CREATE VIEW AS users_with_their_images AS
  SELECT u.id, 
    uis.url AS small_image_url,
    uim.url AS medium_image_url,
    uil.url AS large_image_url
  FROM users AS u
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_images uis ON uis.id = u.small_image_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_images uim ON uim.id = u.medium_image_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_images uil ON uil.id = u.large_image_id;
```

That's the thing about joins: it sticks together, side by side, **one** row from each table in the join.

If you want multiple rows added to this, then you need multiple joins.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to join `users` with the `user_images` table three times here:

```
CREATE VIEW user_image_urls AS
SELECT u.user_id,
       u.user_name,
       COALESCE(t1.small_image_url,  'NA'),
       COALESCE(t2.medium_image_url, 'NA'),
       COALESCE(t3.large_image_url,  'NA')
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_images t1
    ON u.small_image_id = t1.small_image_id
LEFT JOIN user_images t2
    ON u.medium_image_id = t2.medium_image_id
LEFT JOIN user_images t3
    ON u.large_image_id = t3.large_image_id
```

I used left joins here to allow for the possibility that certain users might not have a given URL defined.  Using an inner join could cause the user to be removed from the result set, which probably is not what you want.  Instead, I list `'NA'` for a URL which be missing.